# What's the error as "CMAKE_BOOTSTRAP_BINARY_DIR" at a time as build CMake from a source code

Tags: build, cmake

What's the error as "CMAKE_BOOTSTRAP_BINARY_DIR". How can I build cmake from the source.

Environment:

- System: Kubuntu-15.04
- CMake source: https://github.com/Kitware/CMake

Reproduction:

```
git clone git@github.com:Kitware/CMake.git
cd CMake
git checkout v3.2.2
./bootstrap
```

Error ( at ./bootstrap ):

```
---------------------------------------------
g++  -I/home/usagi/repos/CMake/Bootstrap.cmk -I/home/usagi/repos/CMake/Source   -I/home/usagi/repos/CMake/Bootstrap.cmk -c /home/usagi/repos/CMake/Source/cmSystemTools.cxx -o cmSystemTools.o
/home/usagi/repos/CMake/Source/cmSystemTools.cxx: In static member function ‘static void cmSystemTools::FindCMakeResources(const char*)’:
/home/usagi/repos/CMake/Source/cmSystemTools.cxx:2195:13: error: ‘CMAKE_BOOTSTRAP_BINARY_DIR’ was not declared in this scope
   exe_dir = CMAKE_BOOTSTRAP_BINARY_DIR "/bin";
             ^
/home/usagi/repos/CMake/Source/cmSystemTools.cxx:2249:28: error: ‘CMAKE_BOOTSTRAP_SOURCE_DIR’ was not declared in this scope
   cmSystemToolsCMakeRoot = CMAKE_BOOTSTRAP_SOURCE_DIR;
                            ^
Makefile:88: recipe for target 'cmSystemTools.o' failed
make: *** [cmSystemTools.o] Error 1
---------------------------------------------
Error when bootstrapping CMake:
Problem while running make
```

Note:

- "/home/usagi/repos" is a repository pool directory in my account.( "usagi" is my user name in this system.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the solution at try on the after a lunch time.

The solution:

```
rm *
git checkout -f

./configure # In the environment, it is not require "./bootstrap".

make
```

"./bootstrap" is not needed in this environment.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem in mac and spending a lot of time,
it was the best download cmake dmg from:

https://cmake.org/download/
(and only added cmake to the path)

and it runs great.

There is some extra information that I found about the bugs in cmake

https://cmake.org/pipermail/cmake-commits/2014-June/019853.html

best,
I.